# Checking length of a String and using do-while in Java

Tags: java, do-while

I want to create a program where you enter a string and it checks if the length is 9 or not. If it is, it gives a message that it is okay. If not, it will give a message that is not, and prompt the user to enter the string again. While running it, I always get that is wrong. Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Sec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Secnum = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give Sec: ");
        String Sec = Secnum.nextLine();
        do{
            if (Sec.length()!= 9);
            System.out.println("Wrong lenght Sec,enter again");
            Secnum.nextLine();
        }while (Sec.length() == 9);
        System.out.println("Sec lenght okay");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to request a new value as long as the length is NOT 9.

So your loop should have that as condition. Further your if is incorrect. If in Java needs curly braces else it will effect the next statement only. A statement can be only a semi-colon as well. So your if-statement is completely useless.

To make the code even more compact you can take out the if and swap the do-while loop. That will only run if the condition is true and not once in the beginning no matter the condition.

A code that should work better:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sec {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner secnum = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give Sec: ");
    String sec = secnum.nextLine();

    while (sec.length() != 9) {
      System.out.println("Wrong lenght Sec,enter again");
      secnum.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Sec lenght okay");
  }
}
```

On a side note: Use lowercase variable names. That is the better code-style :)

Comment: Thank you geisterfurz007 for all the tips and suggestions. As I stated, I'm a beginner, self-teaching from a book, (and book in Greek), so I'm still missing a lot .

Comment: You are welcome! Everyone starts like that ;) If the answer helped to solve your problem, consider upvoting it (and any other one you think helped, of course). If it fully answered your question, accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark on the left side of the answer. This will mark the question as solved for others and will reward me as well as you!

Comment: Thanks ! I upvoted - of course - but because of my reputation (lack of it) it doesn't show. I will accept the answer, great ! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are terminating the if statement.

> `if (Sec.length()!= 9);`

So, the next print always executes irrespective of it being true or not.

Put the logic for failure inside an `if` block.

```
if (Sec.length()!= 9) {
    // Print failure message
    // Other logic
}
```

Comment: Do you want to continue the loop till the user gives a correct input?

Comment: No, I don't. Once it gives the correct input, I will use the Sec for other calculations. Thank you